# Load more button using Javascript

Tags: javascript, twig

I am trying to implement a "Load more" button in order to display 12 posts and then an additional 12 posts after every time the load more button are clicked.

The button works fine, but I am not sure what to do in order for it to start off with displaying 12 posts, as it starts with only 2 posts and then displays 12 more with every click.

Please find the code below:

HTML (with Twig):

```
  <div class="list">
      {% for post in posts %}
          <div class="list-element">
              <div class="product">
                  {{ post.location }}
              </div>
          </div>
      {% endfor %}
</div>

<!-- Load More Button -->
<button id="loadmore">Load More...</button>
```

CSS:

```
.list-element {
    perspective: 1500px;
    margin: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    width: 380px;
    height: 375px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
    transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px;
    display: none;
}

.list-element .content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.75, 0, 0.85, 1);
}

#loadmore {
    margin: 15px auto 0px;
    display: table;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: rgb(84, 187, 98);
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: solid 1px green;
}

.list .list-element:nth-child(1) {
    display: block;
}

.list .list-element:nth-child(2) {
    display: block;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
    const loadmore = document.querySelector('#loadmore');
    let currentItems = 12;
    loadmore.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        const elementList = [...document.querySelectorAll('.list .list-element')];
        for (let i = currentItems; i < currentItems + 12; i++) {
            if (elementList[i]) {
                elementList[i].style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
        currentItems += 12;

        // Load more button will be hidden after list fully loaded
        if (currentItems >= elementList.length) {
            event.target.style.display = 'none';
        }
    })
```